# c# html sent by httpResponse, but opened as text

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, server

i have a B/S application, and i write the server myself with c#.

On the server side, i have an `httpListener` listens on port 35349 and an  `httpRequestHandler` like:

```
private static void httpRequestHandler(httpListenerContext ctx){
   //check if it's a request for files
   if(ctx.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Length > 0){

      //read the file into byte array "buffer"
      string path = _appFilePath + ctx.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace('/','\\');
      byte[] buffer;
      try{
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
         buffer = new byte[info.Length];
         fs.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(info.Length));
         fs.Close();
      }
      catch{
         return;
      }

      //send data back
      ctx.Response.Headers.Add("HttpResponseStatus:OK");
      ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
      ctx.Response.ContentType = "HTML";
      ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      ctx.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
      ctx.Response.Close();
   }
}
```

and an html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=chrome" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   </head>

   <body>....</body>
</html>
```

and in the browser i type the address as **`http://192.168.1.16:35349/test.html`**, it shows me the html as text!

THE PROBLEM IS: i want an html page after i type the address, but not a text page. so how should i modify my codes?

Answer (score 1):

The [`ContextType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx) header actually expects a valid MIME type that represents the response, so you'll want to use `text/html` or simply remove that line altogether as it's the default:

```
// Either remove this line from your current code or set it to "text/html"
ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Comment: removing it won't work, but yes, it works by "text/html". thanks a lot!